# Wine not working?

Tags: wine

I tried installing a poker app,from this [site](https://www.poker.gr/)

I downloaded the file,clicked install using wine (i have the latest version of wine)

The installation completed ok,but when I try to open the app,it opens,then almost immediately shuts down..Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the output when installing the app from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The best option for non-commercial use is VMware Player. You just need to make an image (.iso) file of your Windows cd and install it on virtual machine. You can run pretty much anything on virtual Windows platform.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Thank you for providing this answer. I just wanted to note, that the question was asked 1 year ago and there hasn't been any activity since. I like your answer it's just a shame that the question is in a bit of bad shape.

Answer (score 0):

Wine isn't perfect, far from it. There's no guarantee for app compatibility. You might find some tips and tricks on running your application in the [Wine app database](http://www.winehq.org/search/?cx=partner-pub-0971840239976722%3Aw9sqbcsxtyf&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=poker&siteurl=appdb.winehq.org%2F&ref=www.winehq.org%2F&ss=415j70129j4). If it's an obscure one, you're on your own, I fear.